# How to implementing custom stemming on elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana

this is my first time working with `elasticsearch` and I use version `7.17.9` on `ubuntu` server, I found this `python` library for stemming `PersianStemmer`, How can I use this library for stemming the text on `elasticsearch`

Comment: for my curiosity, was the Persian analyzer not helpful? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#persian-analyzer

Comment: it doesn't have `stemming`